# Can i print a specific text with custom color?

Tags: vb.net, colors

I want to print text in textbox that already contains some text, and i wonder is it possible to print text with custom color in only one line :

```
    If receivedData.Contains("close") Then
        TextBox1.Text &= "CARD STATUS: "
        TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        TextBox1.Text &= "Card Locked" & vbCrLf
        TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    End If
```

It doesnt change forecolor...

Comment: That's not printing; it's just displaying. The answer is no, you cannot do that in a `TextBox`.  You would have to use a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: THe same happening with RTB, it doesnt change color with this code

Comment: No it won't with that code. You need to use the appropriate code for a `RichTextBox`. You can learn how to do that with a simple web search.